# Output from google dataflow to google cloud firestore

Tags: java, json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow

Good day, after A-lot of struggling trying to get to grips with this technology ( dataflow ) I've managed to get the pipeline working 100%.

What it does is load a bunch of CSV files into the pipeline ( From google cloud storage ), transform them into "Domain" objects and then save them in JSON format to a file.

What I'd like to do instead though is take the JSON object and push it to a database ( google cloud firestore ) directly.

The final transform that I apply to my data at this stage is :

```
.apply(DatastoreIO.v1().write().withProjectId("____"));
```

As I understand that call requires the previous transform to return an Entity object, which I am unable to create

```
public Entity toEntity() {
    Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    Key taskKey = datastore.newKeyFactory().setKind("Task").newKey("Test");
    Entity e = Entity.newBuilder(taskKey).set("Domain", domain)
            .set("LocationOnsite", locOnSite)
            .set("Company", company).build();

    return e;
}
```

this returns a com.google.cloud.datastore.Entity instead of the required com.google.datastore.v1.Entity

I think its worth noting that the "Domain" object also contains some ArrayLists of other objects such as "Emails" which needs to be included into the database.

Below is a sample JSON output that I currently have :

```
{
   "Vertical": "Business And Industrial",
   "Zip": "35229",
   "Company": "Alabama Association of Nonprofits",
   "QuantCast": "229219",
   "Twitter": "",
   "Vimeo": "",
   "LocationOnSite": "",
   "LastIndexed": "2018-02-01",
   "Pinterest": "",
   "Youtube": "",
   "TechSpend": "$250+",
   "Emails": [
      {
         "Email": "shannon@alabamanonprofits.org"
      },
      {
         "Email": "support@alabamanonprofits.org"
      },
      {
         "Email": "carla@alabamanonprofits.org"
      },
      {
         "Email": "kellie@alabamanonprofits.org"
      },
      {
         "Email": "ashley@alabamanonprofits.org"
      },
      {
         "Email": "Unknown"
      }
   ],
   "Facebook": "",
   "Google+": "",
   "Alexa": "",
   "Github": "",
   "FirstIndexed": "2011-01-03",
   "People": [
      {
         "Email": "Unknown",
         "Name": "Joshua Cirulnick"
      },
      {
         "Email": "Unknown",
         "Position": "Other",
         "Name": " Elaine Lin"
      },
      {
         "Email": "Unknown",
         "Position": "Other",
         "Name": " Terry Burkle"
      },
      {
         "Email": "Unknown",
         "Position": "Director",
         "Name": " Ashley Gilbert"
      },
      {
         "Email": "Unknown",
         "Position": "President",
         "Name": " Carol Weisman"
      },
      {
         "Email": "Unknown",
         "Position": "Csuite",
         "Name": " Shannon Ammons"
      },
      {
         "Email": "Unknown",
         "Position": "Founder",
         "Name": " Kelly McDonald"
      }
   ],
   "City": "Birmingham",
   "Telephone#s": [
      {
         "Telephone#": "+1-205-879-4712"
      },
      {
         "Telephone#": "+1-205-871-7740"
      }
   ],
   "FirstDetected": "N/A",
   "LinkedIn": "",
   "VK": "",
   "State": "AL",
   "Instagram": "",
   "Country": "US",
   "Domain": "alabamanonprofits.org",
   "LastFound": "N/A"
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to effectively get objects such as these into the google cloud firestore database, I'd be very happy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write the data to Cloud Pub/Sub, which can trigger a function to write the data to Cloud Firestore.  There was a great example of this at Google I/O 2017, which does the same thing, but with the Realtime Database.

You can watch it here: [Data Pipelines with Firebase and Google Cloud (Google I/O '17)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=guo-4IOqx2M)

Comment: Thanks this seems very viable! I'll check it out